# Select multiple users from database using ajax - php

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to make a list of members from database who should recieve my message . 
[Link](http://www.excoflare.com/dev2011/socialnetwork/index.php?menu=set_event) . When the user selects "private use only"
the user will be able to select members of his choice .I am confused how to achieve this goal . Can you help me in this ? Any
link to related tutorial will also be helpful to me .

Answer (score 0):

you need to display a combo-box using ajax.

try this code for that,

```
<div id="user_combo"></div>

function ajax_combo(btn_var)
{

    jQuery("#user_combo").html('<center>Loading... </center>');
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax_user_combo.php",
            data:   "radio="+btn_var,
            success: function(html){
                jQuery("#user_combo").html(html);

            }
        });

}
```

call this function onClick event of that radio button. and check if checked value is `private use only` or not.

and in `ajax_uer_combo.php` you can put query of retrieving all users you want to display in select box.

Try this.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Chandresh. I will try and inform you